# Blender 2.8 UV Sculpt Brush not showing

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Well, I was triying to edit some UVs on the latest Blender 2.8 Beta build, and when I tried to use the traditional UV sculpt tool from Blender's uv editor, I couldn't,  the brush simply does not show up, so I can't use it.

So the question is: Am I missing something or is this a bug from the current build?

If I'm correct, this icons activate the UV sculpt brush functionality but currently they do nothing.

[image]

Also I already made sure to have the UV Sculpt option activated
[image]

Comment: You should report it as a bug. It is broken.

Answer (score -3):

If you create a blend file in 2.79 and then open it with 2.8 the UV sculpt works.